# Logback and SMTPAppender Issue

Tags: java, spring, logback

I added Logback to my Spring Boot project and it works when writing in files or standard output. Now I would like to send log emails, but if I try to configure the SMTPAppender, I get the following error:

> Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from
>   'logback-spring.xml' java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback
>   configuration error detected:  ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Could not create an
>   Appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender].
>   ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to
>   instantiate type ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@8:76 - ActionException in
>   Action for tag [appender]
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ActionException:
>   ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to
>   instantiate type ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Could not find an
>   appender named [EMAIL]. Did you define it below instead of above in
>   the configuration file? ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - See
>   http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#appender_order for more details.     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:162)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:66)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:115)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:276)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:239)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:212)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:336)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
>     at
>   org.lh.cfpappserver.CfpAppServerApplication.main(CfpAppServerApplication.java:10)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Could not
>   create an Appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender].
>   ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to
>   instantiate type ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@8:76 - ActionException in
>   Action for tag [appender]
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ActionException:
>   ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to
>   instantiate type ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Could not find an
>   appender named [EMAIL]. Did you define it below instead of above in
>   the configuration file? ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - See
>   http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#appender_order for more details.     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:315)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:276)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:239)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:212)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:336)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
>     at
>   org.lh.cfpappserver.CfpAppServerApplication.main(CfpAppServerApplication.java:10)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration
>   error detected:  ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Could not create an
>   Appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender].
>   ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to
>   instantiate type ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@8:76 - ActionException in
>   Action for tag [appender]
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ActionException:
>   ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to
>   instantiate type ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Could not find an
>   appender named [EMAIL]. Did you define it below instead of above in
>   the configuration file? ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - See
>   http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#appender_order for more details.     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:162)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:66)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:115)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:308)
>     ... 13 more

This is my configuration in logback-spring.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml"/>


    <appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
        <asynchronousSending>false</asynchronousSending>
        <smtpHost>smtp.gmail.com</smtpHost>
        <to>my email</to>
        <from>my email</from>
        <username>xxx</username>
        <password>xxx</password>
        <subject>%logger{20} - %m</subject>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout"/>
        <cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTracker">
            <bufferSize>1</bufferSize>
        </cyclicBufferTracker>
        <starttls>true</starttls>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="org.lh.cfpappserver.util.StdOutFilter"/>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="EMAIL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

What's wrong in my configuration preventing the application to start?